# Prevent Caller Routine Error Capture in Visual Basic 6

Tags: error-handling, vb6, global-variables

I've got a bug occuring in my Visual Basic 6 program (originally written by someone else), where a (global) flag is set that should always be reset before the end of the routine. Sometimes (rarely, incosistently) it isn't. As far as I can tell it will always be reset in normal flow having looked at the subroutines in question.

My best guess is to how this flag is being left set is that there is error handling in a calling function (of which there may be many) that is improperly handling the error, possibly with a "Resume Next". Is there any way I can stop the sub I am interested in from passing on the error to the higher level hander, *while also showing me the line on which the error occured and the original error*? (Obviously I could wrap the subs in question in On error tags and have a msgbox prompt, but that would leave me pretty lost as to where the actual error occured)

Comment: Why not put a Watch on the variable to break if it changes and you are not in the correct state?

Comment: It changes to often for that to be useful - will be breaking all the time - and the bug is in it *not* changins.

Comment: Is this a single routine you are talking about? Or a number of distinct routines, which all use the same flag setting / resetting?

Comment: And could you use "Break on All Errors"?

Comment: There are 3 routines which set/reset the flag. These are called from I have no idea how many places. Break on All Errors might work, will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your last comment, you say that there are three routines. Since that isn't too onerous, I would recommend using the following pattern:

```
Sub Routine_n()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ... code ...

    g_bGlobalFlag = False

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    g_bGlobalFlag = False
    Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description
End Sub
```

The usual danger about adding code to error handlers is that you inadvertently reset the Err object. The response to this is to save the Err object's properties to temporary variables, and reraise the error using these temporary variables. However, in this case since setting a boolean variable cannot cause an error condition, it is quite reasonable to simply reset the flag before reraising the error.

Comment: If my guess had been right, then that would have been a (hacky) solution to the problem. As it was however, running with "Break on All" revealed that there were no exceptions, handled or otherwise.

Instead the problem turned out to be a timeout loop with "DoEvents", that let another routine interrupt without taking over. Removing the accursed DoEvents has solved this (and a couple of other) problems

Comment: Aargh! DoEvents is evil!